# Find 3D point along the line at given distance

Tags: line, distance, direction

I have a problem and please let me know if my solution is correct.

I have a known point, at location A(x1,y1,z1) and the origin O(0,0,0) and I would like to find the coordinates of a point B(x2,y2,z2) that is located on the line OA, and the distance OB is 1.2 times greater then OA.

So, my idea is to obtain the equation of the line formed by points O and A. 
The direction of OA is (-x1, -y1, -z1), so the equation of the line is:

x = -x1*t;

y = -y1*t;

z = -z1*t;

Distance OA is sqrt( (x1-0)^2 + (y1-0)^2 + (z1-0)^2). KNOWN

Distance OB is sqrt( (x2-0)^2 + (y2-0)^2 + (z2-0)^2). UNKNOWN

I can replace the x, y, z points determined for the line equation in the distance OB, and the result should be 1.2 times greater then the distance OA.

So, sqrt( (-x1*t-0)^2 + (-y1*t-0)^2 + (-z1*t-0)^2) = 1.2 * dist(OA).

I find t from here, solving the quadratic equation and I obtain the coordinates of the point by replacing the t in the equation of the line.

Is this correct?

Thank you for your time.

EDIT:
This is my code:

```
rangeRatio = 1.114;

norm = sqrt((P2(1) - P1(1))^2 + (P2(2) - P1(2))^2 + (P2(3) - P1(3))^2);

P3(1) = P1(1) + ((P2(1,1) - P1(1)) /norm) * rangeRatio;
P3(2) = P1(2) + ((P2(1,2) - P1(2)) /norm) * rangeRatio;
P3(3) = P1(3) + ((P2(1,3) - P1(3)) /norm) * rangeRatio;
```

I tried also norm = 1, and i get slightly different results but still not always colinear.

Thank you

Comment: Wow, you have over-complicated the problem.

Answer (score 4):

It is even a lot easier; you can just multiply a, b and c by 1.2. This gives a line that is 1.2 times the size of the original line.

Comment: You mean `x`, `y` and `z` instead of a,b,c?

Comment: Umm yeah of course. Or, put differently then, `x2 = 1.2 * x1`, `y2 = 1.2 * y1` and `z2 = 1.2 * z1`

Comment: Can you explain a little please?

Comment: You want to say that if you have two points O and A, a third point B with the coordinates as a multiple of the coordinates of A will be on the line determined by O and A?
It doesn't seem possiblr

Comment: Given that O equals (0,0,0), it's simple vector multiplication. With a point A (x,y,z), the line OA represents a vector with direction (x,y,z). A point along the same line is a multiplication of this vector with a factor lambda. The length of the line then also multiplies with factor lambda. So `1.2 * (x,y,z) = (1.2x, 1.2y, 1.2z)` and that represents a point on the line OA.

Comment: And if instead of the origin another point M(xm, ym, zm) is used together with a point A(x, y, z), then point B(x2,y2,z2) would have the coordinates x2 = xm + (xm-x)*t ; y2 = ym + (ym-y)*t ; z2 = zm + (zm-z)*t ; where t is the ratio between distances, here  1.2. Is this correct?

Comment: If you want the line MB and MA in the same direction, then you should not use `(xm-x)`, but `(x-xm)` (and the same for y and z).

So `x2 = xm + (x-xm)*t ; y2 = ym + (y-ym)*t ; z2 = zm + (z-zm)*t`.

Comment: I have implemented exactly as you said, and I have tested the colinearity by applying the cross product on MB * MA, and by checking the slope between the MB and MA. When I apply the cross product one axis is 0 and the rest very close to 0 (like x= 0 y= 0.005 and z =  0.02) and very rare I get all axis values equal to 0. THe same happens also with the slope computation. Instead of getting always 0, i sometimes get values like 0.03 or 0.007. DO you have any idea why? Is it normal? Or can it be a tolerated error?

Comment: I don't know why you get these errors, but this is the way to do it... A line in 3D equals `P + D*t` with P a fixed point and D a direction, both a 3-dimensional vector. t is a scalar number.

Comment: I do not understand why for some cases the points are colinear and in some cases not.